# How can I start transmission-daemon service before login?

Tags: autostart, transmission

I want to run transmission-daemon as a service so that any user can log in and access the same instance of Transmission (via the browser or Transmission remote GUI).

Is this possible, and how can I do it?

Comment: also asked at https://forum.transmissionbt.com/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=11489

Comment: seems like http://www.marzocca.net/linux/bum.html might be part of the answer

Comment: could be the answer http://wl500g.info/showthread.php?t=12436

Comment: password issue http://superuser.com/questions/113649/how-do-you-set-a-password-for-transmission-daemon-the-bittorrent-client-server

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You just install the [transmission-daemon](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/transmission-daemon)
 package and it'll be started automatically during boot via the init script it installs. The instance that is started via the init script will be run as the user `debian-transmission`, and it reads `/etc/transmission-daemon/settings.json` as the configuration file.

See https://trac.transmissionbt.com/wiki/EditConfigFiles on how to edit `settings.json`. Remember to run `pkill -HUP transmission-d` after editing `settings.json`, otherwise your changes will be overwritten next time transmission-daemon is stopped.

Comment: additional notes https://trac.transmissionbt.com/wiki/UnixServer/Debian